# SVN: What is the difference between 'Base Revision' and 'Latest from Repository'?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

While comparing a local file in workspace with the one in repository, I came across: Compare with >> 'Base revision' and Compare with >>  'Latest from repository'.

So, I want to know what is the difference between 'Base Revision' and 'Latest from Repository'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Base revision" is the last revision you have obtained from the repository. "Latest from repository" is the most recent code that the repository has.

Source: [when-does-svn-base-become-equal-to-the-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742772/when-does-svn-base-become-equal-to-the-head)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After reading your answer, I immediately remembered the concept, which was somewhere hidden deep in my memory, since not used SVN for quite a long time.

Answer (score 10):

"Base revision" is also known as `BASE`, which is: The revision number of an item in a working copy. If the item has been locally modified, this refers to the way the item appears without those local modifications.

"Latest from repository" is `HEAD`, which is: The latest (or "youngest") revision in the repository.

(Taken from [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords))